# Can I increase CFM by combining two ducts into one?

Tags: hvac, ducts, air

From the plenum can I connect two 6" takeoffs into a single 8" with a Wye, then run 20 feet of 8" flex, then split again into two 6" via a Wye and go to to two separate rooms?

Does combining the two 6" into 8" increase my CFM?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What actual problem are you looking to resolve? The area of a 6" pipe is 28 sq in. Two of those gives you 56 sq in. The area of an 8" pipe is 50 sq in. Therefore you're actually loosing room to move air though, so the answer to your question is "NO" it won't increase CFM.

Comment: So I do increase my cfm off the 6"...

Comment: I am just trying to run 1 duct flex to on side of the house and split it again to two separate room. Each room is 100 sqft

Comment: Use smooth/rigid duct rather than flex *to improve flow* in the duct. Flex has a lot of flow-friction due to the shape of the inside of it.

Comment: You're simply trying to eliminate one duct run? A 10" duct is 78.5 sq in, so that would not restrict your air flow.

Comment: If going to 10", you'll do better capping one or both 6" take offs and adding or increasing one to 10" than the cockamamie combine 6" at the plenum end idea.

Comment: On the plenum I have two 6" take off , I can't change anything on that part. So my plan is to connect does 2 together in a wye form to 8" or 10" then run the flex 20 ft out to each room